# How to combine multiple Feeds and Filter them?

Tags: youtube, feed

I have over 400 feeds that are from YouTube channels that I want to combine into just one feed that can be filtered by date, so it only displays from x date to y date.

**Example of what the feed looks like**: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/google/uploads

I have already tried to use different web services but they have all failed to work. I have tried yahoo pipes but I'm not really sure how I would be able to combine hundreds of feeds using it.

Why I need to do this is because I have a Wordpress Plugin that can post content via feeds, but 400 is too much and I only need current content from that feed. Please can anyone give me some suggestions on how I can combine all these feeds then filter them? Or possibly suggest some alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Yahoo Pipes - http://pipes.yahoo.com